# ¿Porque este UseEffect no se activa en este caso?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-native, useeffect, native

Tengo este useEffect que se activa en el caso de que Provincia obtenga un nuevo valor.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (provincia && provincia !== "" && provincia !== undefined) {
        console.log("TRAIGO NUEVAS VARIABLES");
        // @ts-ignore
        AxiosHealth.get(`provincias/${provincia.id}/localidades`)
            .then((value) => {
                // Manejar la respuesta de la petición
                setLocalidadSelect(value.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error + " Error en las provincias");
            });
    }
}, [provincia]);
```

Ahora... El problema recae cuando utilizo el setProvincia en esta parte:

```
 <Button mode="contained" theme={{ colors: { primary: Colores.primary } }} icon="border-color" 
                                              onPress={() => {
                                                setClinicaEditar([]);
                                                setClinicaEditar(clinica); //Guardo el array del editable seleccionado
                                                const nombreProvincia = clinica.direccion?.provincia;
                                                const provinciaEncontrada = provinciaSelect.find((item) => item.nombre === nombreProvincia);
                                                setProvincia(provinciaEncontrada); //Aca surje el problema, ya lo teste con console.log y en todos los casos modifica el Provincia
                                                const nombreLocalidad = clinica.direccion?.localidad; //Obtiene el nombre de localidad

                                                const localidadEncontrada = localidadSelect.find((item) => item.nombre === nombreLocalidad); //Al no activarse el useEffect el localidadSelect resulta ser nulo, por lo tanto rompe en esta linea.
                                                setLocalidad(localidadEncontrada);
                                                // Configurar otros campos de edición
                                                setmostrarModalEditar(true);
                                              }}>EDITAR</Button>
```

En resumen... El useEffect anteriormente mencionado no se activa al momento de setearse con "setProvincia(provinciaEncontrada)" por alguna rara razon el "useEffect" no se activa...
Por lo que no encuentro alguna razon del por que no se activa si provincia se modifica.

Comment: Probaste colocando un console.log arriba de todo en el useEffect()? que te apareció?

Comment: Buenas Infinit3Loop_, si exactamente intente eso mismo pero no ingresa.
Lo intente fuera y dentro de la condicional. Directamente no me devolvio ningun dato o texto en duro como "Console.log("Entre al useEffect")"

Comment: Ah no intente lo de hacer una funcion handler! Lo puse directamente. Y provinciaEncontrada me devuelve un array entero con dos datos los cuales son Id Y Nombre, en caso de no devolver nada me rompe el proyecto causando que lo tenga que reiniciar.
El valor por defecto de Provincia es vacio, seria "([])".

Comment: @la api es gratuita? el problema es que no puedo probar tu código porque no tengo acceso a la api

Comment: Seria mejor si brindas mas información, estaba intentando replicar tu código pero necesitaría la estructura de los json `clinica, provinciaSelect, localidadSelect` para así simular la consulta.